# How to raise property changed events of two user controls in MVVM

Tags: c#, silverlight

in my view, i have two chart controls of type MyChart:

MyChart1
MyChart2

The chart user control has a button called Refresh.  Clicking on the button refreshes their item source and they display new data.

In the ViewModel of the view, I have two properties of type MyChart, one for each MyChart.

When I click on the Refresh button, how do I raise RaisePropertyChanged event of the view model of the view?

Comment: I'm not an expert on silverlight so others can give better answers but as a quick and easy fix, you could just re-bind the property to the current value. The re-binding will probably trigger the `PropertyChanged` event.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a correct implementation of MVVM, as you have application logic coded into the View layer.

The standard approach would be to have a Command property on your ViewModel, then bind Button.Command to the ViewModel.Command.  This will allow you to handle the refreshing in the ViewModel and give you a place to write any additional code you need to write.

To answer your question, if you are using MVVM, the properties displayed in the View actually exist in the ViewModel, so you should be able to handle PropertyChanged easily enough in the ViewModel using `this.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(ViewModel_PropertyChanged);`

Comment: Why would you need to fiddle with the `PropertyChanged` handler at all?  You would just get the command to _call_ `PropertyChanged` twice, once for each property bound to the charts.

Comment: @Anthony: You're right - but part of the question is "how do I raise RaisePropertyChanged event of the view model".

Comment: The answer is you call it in the Execute method of the Command implementation.